# i get ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946) error from webview in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, webview

I want to use webview in my project in flutter.
i called a url in webview and i see a white page. in log i see this error:

```
E/chromium( 5310): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

I didn't have any error for other domain

notice:
1- I have this problem in android only.
2- I used the android project with java and get this problem too.

Code:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart' as web;Scaffold(
      

appBar: new AppBar(
            title: InkWell(
              child: isLoading == true
                  ? Loading(
                      indicator: BallPulseIndicator(),
                      size: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                  : Text("اپلیکیشن آرایشگاه"),
              onTap: () {
                _webViewControllerFuture.loadUrl("domain");
              },
            ),
          ),
          body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: web.WebView(
                key: key,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _webViewControllerFuture = webViewController;
                },
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                initialUrl: 'https://domain',
                javascriptMode: web.JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onPageStarted: (String url) {
                  if (url == "https://domain")
                    scan();
                  else if (!_isBack)
                    setState(() {
                      isLoading = true;
                    });
                },
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  _isBack = false;
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
```

Comment: please insert the code snippet, that is causing the error

Comment: question has been edited

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error with the `webview_flutter` plugin version is `2.0.4` (beta).

I used this version for about 2 years and don't have any issues. Now, when I meet this issue, I upgraded this plugin to version `2.5.0` and the issue was gone.

Maybe the version you used too old, I think you should upgrade it up to <3.0 version bcz from 3.0 version is BREAKING CHANGE :D